# How to make boost::serialization deserialization faster?

Tags: c++, performance, serialization, boost

I use boost::serialization to save an object that contains this data :

```
struct Container
{
    struct SmallObject
    {
        struct CustomData
        {
            unsigned first;
            float second;
        };

        std::vector<CustomData> customData; // <- i can have 1 to 4 of these in the std::vector
        float data1[3];
        float data2[3];
        float data3[2];
        float data4[4];
    };

    std::vector<SmallObject> mySmallerObjects;  // <- i can have 8000 to 13000 of the std::vector
};
```

The serialization code looks like this (this in the intrusive version, I didn't write the functions declaration above for readability purposes) :

```
template<class Archive> void Container::SmallObject::CustomData::serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/)
{
    ar & first;
    ar & second;
}

template<class Archive> void Container::SmallObject::serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/)
{
    ar & customData;
    ar & data1
    ar & data2;
    ar & data3;
    ar & data4;
}

template<class Archive> void Container::serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*version*/)
{
    ar & mySmallerObjects;
}
```

I use binary_archives. In release mode, loading my container (with 12000 small objects) takes about 400 milliseconds. I am told this is too long. Are there any settings or different memory layouts that would speed up the loading process ? Shall I giveup using boost::serialization ?

Comment: Are those 400ms just to read the objects from the disk?

Comment: @karlphillip and @ildjarn : I benchmarked separately the part that loads the file from the disk (including creating the boost archive) and the effective deserialization part (just the statement "archive>>data;" actually). The disk reading part was a few milliseconds, the effective deserialization was 390 ms.

Comment: How many bytes are we talking about?

Comment: @karlphillip : 1.07 MB (1,130,496 bytes on disk)

Comment: @wil : As a sanity check, how exactly did you load the file from disk entirely before deserialization?

Comment: @ildjarn: I have other container structures so I wrote the loading function as a template function : `template<class Serializable> void loadArchive(std::string archiveFileName, Serializable& data)
{
  std::ifstream fileStream(archiveFileName.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
  assert(fileStream);
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(fileStream);
  archive >> data;  // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
}`
Typically I would call it like that :
`Container container;
loadArchive("container.bin", container);`

Comment: @wil : But, that code doesn't load the file into memory before deserializing... What code did you use to determine that disk reading was only ~10ms?

Comment: I used something like this :
`void loadArchive(...)
{
    StartCounter();
    std::ofstream fileStream(archiveFileName.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(fileStream);
    double timeToLoad = GetCounter();
    /*...*/
}
`
How do I load the file into memory in the above block ? Is it something like `fileStream.rdbuf()->pubsync()` ? (Please excuse my inexperience).

Comment: @wil : No worries. :-] Create the `ofstream` as you do, then do `std::stringstream buf; buf << fileStream.rdbuf(); buf.seekg(0);`, then deserialize with `buf` rather than `fileStream`. Benchmark from after the `seekg` call, and that's your actual deserialization time. Let us know.

Comment: @wil : Er, one clarification: how would an `std::ofstream` be of use when _loading_ an archive..?

Comment: @ildjarn:sorry for the typo, i use std::ifstream indeed.

Comment: @wil : (Of course, make sure to create the `stringstream` with `ios_base::binary` as well, or data corruption will result.)

Comment: @ildjarn:when trying to create the archive from the string buffer, I get a "boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location 0x..." error message when creating the archive object. Here is my code:
`
void loadArchive(...)
{
  std::ifstream fileStream(archiveFileName.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
  std::stringstream buf(std::ios::binary);
  buf << fileStream.rdbuf();
  buf.seekg(0);
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(buf);
StartCounter();
  archive >> data;
double d3 = GetCounter();
}
` What is rong ?

Comment: @wil : I updated my answer with code that works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to pick the single biggest drawback of Boost.Serialization, it would be poor performance. If 400ms is truly too slow, either get faster hardware or switch to a different serialization library.

That said, just in case you're doing something blatantly "wrong", you should post the serialization code for `Container`, `Container::SmallObject`, and `Container::SmallObject::CustomData`. You should also ensure that it's actually deserialization that's taking 400ms, and not a combination of deserializing + reading the data from the disk; i.e., load the data into a memory-stream of some sort and deserialize from that, rather than deserializing from an `std::fstream`.

---

**EDIT** (in response to comments):

This code works for me using VC++ 2010 SP1 and Boost 1.47 beta:

```cpp
double loadArchive(std::string const& archiveFileName, Container& data)
{
    std::ifstream fileStream(
        archiveFileName.c_str(),
        std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in
    );
    std::stringstream buf(
        std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out
    );
    buf << fileStream.rdbuf();
    fileStream.close();

    StartCounter();
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive(buf) >> data;
    return GetCounter();
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, it must be specific to the compiler and/or version of Boost you're using (which are what?).

On my machine, for an x86 release build (with link-time code generation enabled), loading the data from disk is ~9% of the overall time taken to deserialize a 1.28MB file (1 `Container` containing 13000 `SmallObject` instances, each containing 4 `CustomData` instances); for an x64 release build, loading the data from disk is ~17% of the overall time taken to deserialize a 1.53MB file (same object counts).

Comment: You are right, actually the 400 ms stands for the combination reading data from the disk (using an std::ifstream) + deserializing.
I added the serialization code to the initial question.

Comment: @wil : Then the next thing you need to do is benchmark deserialization from memory rather than disk. If it's sufficiently fast, then disk access is your bottleneck, and there's not a whole lot you can do about that...

Comment: I could compile and run your code without problem, however a strange thing happens, using this method loading the archive is much slower (4500 milliseconds).

Comment: @wil : I'm not sure what to tell you without you posting a full repro... Deserialization for my example file takes ~140ms on my machine. What compiler and version of Boost are you using, and are you 100% positive you're benchmarking builds with optimizations _enabled_?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing the number of items into the serialization stream and then using std::vector::reserve to allocate all the memory you will need. That way, you will be doing the minimum number of allocations.

Comment: Unless he's serializing the contents of each `vector` as a C-array (pointer), rather than serializing the `vector` directly, Boost.Serialization already internally does exactly what you propose.